# Wildfly CLI not working for me

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly-8

All I did was download wildfly-8.1.0.CR2 and extract it. standalone.bat and add-user.bat work but jboss-cli.bat does not.

> F:\wildfly-8.1.0.CR2\bin>jboss-cli

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no jansi64-1.9 in
java.library.path, no jansi-1.9 in java.library.path, no jansi in java.library.path,
D:\pgarner\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64-1.9.dll: The application has failed to start
because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event
log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail]

    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:184)

    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:142)

    at org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.<clinit>(Kernel32.java:37)

    at org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream.<clinit>(WindowsAnsiOutputStream.java:52)

    at org.jboss.aesh.terminal.WindowsTerminal.init(WindowsTerminal.java:53)

    at org.jboss.aesh.console.Console.setTerminal(Console.java:193)

    at org.jboss.aesh.console.Console.reset(Console.java:154)

    at org.jboss.aesh.console.Console.<init>(Console.java:105)

    at org.jboss.aesh.console.Console.<init>(Console.java:101)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.Console$Factory.getConsole(Console.java:85)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.Console$Factory.getConsole(Console.java:78)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.initBasicConsole(CommandContextImpl.java:349)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.<init>(CommandContextImpl.java:296)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextFactoryImpl.newCommandContext(CommandContextFactoryImpl.java:76)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:273)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:253)

    at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)

    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

> 

When I start up Wildfly using standalone.bat I see the following entry for java.library.path in server.log:

> java.library.path = F:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;F:\WANdisco\uberSVN\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\GnuPG\pub;F:\7-Zip;"E:\WebTest\build\bin";F:\WANdisco\uberSVN\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\GnuPG\pub;F:\7-Zip;.

The following file does indeed appear on my file system when I attempt to run jboss-cli:

> D:\pgarner\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64-1.9.dll

I also tried using wildfly-8.0.0.Final instead of wildfly-8.1.0.CR2 and the same exact problem happened.

How to resolve this problem?  I assumed the CLI should just work right out of the box after extracting all the files out of the zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're facing the same error and the problem is due to the jansi dll dependencies. In fact you need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package corresponding to your platform. For x64, you can follow this link :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=2092

Comment: Geesh one would think that this sort of thing would have been known by Wildfly team.  Seems counterintuitive that an app server written in Java would require Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 to be installed!

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem. I can start Wildfly and deploy my application without errors, but everytime I redeploy my application, I get the following error:

Caused by:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no
>   jansi64-1.9 in java.library.path, no jansi-1.9 in java.library.path,
>   no jansi in java.library.path, Native Library
>   C:\Users\zb\AppData\Local\Temp\jansi-64-1.9.dll already loaded in
>   another classloader]

It seems this jansi library is stuck after deploy.

Restarting the server helps temporarily.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem running wildfly as a managed arquillian container on my Windows build server. The first instance runs through, but wenn it wants to create another instance of wildfly this exact error occurs.